# Taking input link for extracting xml data with Python 3

Tags: python, xml, input

Can't use link taken as input.
url = input('Enter location: ') this line is not working. IDE is saying - 'str' object is not callable.

Here's my code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error


url = input('Enter location: ')


uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()

z=0

stuff = ET.fromstring(data)
lst = stuff.findall('comments/comment')
print('count:', len(lst))

for item in lst:
    #print('Name', item.find('name').text)
    #print('count', item.find('count').text)
    y = int(item.find('count').text)
    z = z+y
print("sum :" ,z)
```

Comment: Can you say which site you are trying to get the data from?
It works for me if I input https:// www.google.com (without the space)
You may also want to use beautifulsoup for this

Comment: Can you update the full error trace if possible